# submitting multiple POST requests as multi threads in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, rest

My development stack is `Django/Python`. (that includes Django-REST-framework)
I am currently looking for ways to do multiple distinct API calls.

```
client.py

def submit_order(list_of_orders):
   //submit each element in list_of_orders in thread
   for order in list_of_orders:
      try:
        response=request.POST(order, "www.confidential.url.com")
      except:
         //retry_again
      else:
          if !response.status==200:
              //retry_again
```

In the above method, I am currently submitting order one by one, I want to submit all orders at once. Secondly, I want to retry submission for x times if it fails.
I currently do not know how well to achieve it.

I am looking for ways that python libraries or Django application provide rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Thanks

Comment: You can have a look at [django-celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 2):

As @Selcuk said you can try [django-celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which is a recommended approach in my opinion, but you will need to make some configuration and read some manuals.

On the other hand, you can try using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process_order(order):
    #Handle each order here doing requests.post and then retrying if neccesary 
    pass

def submit_order(list_of_orders):
    orders_pool = Pool(len(list_of_orders))
    results = orders_pool.map(process_order, list_of_orders)
    #Do something with the results here
```

It will depend on what you need to get done, if you can do the requests operations on the background and your api user can be notified later, just use django-celery and then notify the user accordingly, but if you want a simple approach to react immediately, you can use the one I "prototyped" for you.

You should consider some kind of delay on the responses for your requests (as you are doing some POST request). So make sure your POST request don't grow a lot, because it could affect the experience of the API clients calling your services.

Comment: I am writing the client. I need to submit many POST request simultaneously.  But what you suggested using multiprocessing is heavyweight and resource intensive  I suppose.